# Show fields from MySQL DB from Search

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, search

I am trying to show fields from a DB depending on a search

The search criteria will be in the adress bar (e.g /search_results.php?q=tea if the user searches tea)

here is my code:

```
    <?php
$name=$_GET["q"];
if ($name<="0"){echo( "You did not enter a search");  
 }
 else
 {
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: line 513 ' . mysql_error());
   }
mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE $name LIKE '$prodname%' ")or die('Error: Line 519' );
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$prodID=$row['prodID'];
$prodname=$row['prodname'];
$catagory=$row['catagory'];
}

echo"   $prodID , $prodname, $catagory ";        
?>
```

When running the code i get

> Error: Line 519

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: If you are posting about a specific error you **must** include the full error message (with line number) and at least the code on that line and the line before it.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary... I have??...

Comment: What's the full error message? What's line 519? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be aware with the sql injection. You are inserting a variable from $_GET array directly into the query.

About the error, it looks like $name contains not supported characters like spaces, or maybe the products table does not exists.

You can put the table name between "`" characters, and in order to see the error you could change the line by this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `$name` LIKE '$prodname%' ")or die('Error: Line 519 ('.mysql_error().')' );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, changed this linke and now get `Error: Line 519 (Unknown column 'tea' in 'where clause')`